# I'm getting error TS2554 during build but not during dev on my Typescript project

Tags: typescript, npm-build

During dev there's no warnings or compile errors and eveything works fine but on npm run build I get the error TS2554 on a constructor saying Expected 0 - 1 arguments, but got 2.

The constructor has the following definition:
ErrorConstructor

```
ErrorConstructor
(message?: string | undefined, options?: ErrorOptions | undefined) => Error (+1 overload)
```

ErrorOptions

```
interface ErrorOptions {
    cause?: unknown;
}
```

This error happens because I'm passing a cause through the ErrorOptions object and as mentioned above I get no error during dev or compile

```
throw Error('message', {cause: 'cause'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I'd assume the code should be like this:

`throw new Error('message', { cause: 'cause' });`

Classes have to be initialized with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I tried that but error still persists.